# How to click special button with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, clicking

I am trying to use selenium to click certain buttons within the bank of america simulator, but the buttons don't seem to ever click. No new link is reached, which is something I haven't encountered before.

https://message.bankofamerica.com/onlinebanking_demo/OLB_Simulator/

I want to click "Sign in options" and then click "Sign in: Recognized device"

I tried using selenium to click the button and I get no error. Nothing happens at all and the program continues, so I know it's not an issue with not finding the button. My current code is as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://message.bankofamerica.com/onlinebanking_demo/OLB_Simulator/')

sleep(3)

login_button = driver.find_element("id", "landing_sign")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", login_button);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked fine for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://message.bankofamerica.com/onlinebanking_demo/OLB_Simulator/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "landing_sign")).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-labelledby='signInOpt3']")).click()
```

NOTE: Using `sleep` is a bad practice, use `WebDriverWait` and wait for the specific state you need instead.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the ***clickable*** elements you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://message.bankofamerica.com/onlinebanking_demo/OLB_Simulator/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#landing_sign"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/onlinebanking_demo/OLB_Simulator/SignIn/recognized']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: recognized]